# How to fetch pretty advanced relation in Drupal 6 - Views 2?

Tags: drupal, view

I have three content types: `Artist`, `Artwork`, `Exhibition`. An Exhibition has a field `'artworks'` (unlimited values). An Artwork has a field `'artist'` (1 value, required).

And there is the relation I can't seem to find with Views: I want all Exhibitions an Artist ever participated in. Which means: on the Artist page, show all Exhibitions all Artworks of this Artist were ever in.

The problem (I think) is that one field (Exhibition.artworks) has many values. Yet Artwork.artist has just 1 value.

I don't know what the problem is =) but it's not working and I've tried a million things. At this point, I'll accept writing SQL queries, but the drupal content database is so incredibly untransparent that I have no idea what to query and how.

Obviously I'd be happiest with an unhacked Views solution, but I'm not getting my hopes up. Anyone experience with relations like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build dependent relationships that should help you to accomplish this. Use a relationship (Artwork) on exhibition.artworks and a relationship (Artist) on (Artwork).Artist

It would be easier to understand what you're doing with exports of the views & content types.

The database structure for content types in Drupal works as follows;

The node is the base table, with nid as index. Your content types have their own tables, content_type_XXXXXX with all single entry fields (that aren't shared among content types) members of that table. Multiple entry and shared fields get their own table content_field_XXXXXX. All of the tables relate on the nid field, and multiple entry fields use a "delta" to indicate the entry order.